# how to rebuild totality base oracle 10g via fichier dmp

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

What method can yoy suggest me to reconstruct the totality of my oracle database 10.0.2.5 on another windows server (backup server)?

Some detail:

- oracle database 10g release 10.2.0.5.0.
- windows server 2003 32 bit.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you actually have in the DMP file. Is it the full database export, a schema export, ...? "Totally" suggests that it is a full export. If that's so,

- install Oracle and create the database
- create tablespaces
- import the DMP file, e.g.

  ```
  imp system/pwd full=y file=fichier.dmp log=fichier.log
  ```

There are numerous examples of how to do that, there's no point in copy/pasting it over here. I suggest you Google for it.